# Как узнать где используется js-файл?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Есть js-файл, который подключен в нескольких php-файлах. Как внутри js-файла узнать, какой php-файл используется в настоящий момент.

Comment: в тот момент когда исполняется js скрипт, php уже обычно завершился (с некоторыми исключениями, которые вам не грозят). В общем **никак**, если только  вы в php  сами не запишете куда-нить значение `__FILE__`

Answer (score 1):

PHP создает определенную страницу и косвенно  можно определить какой php файл был вызван 
1 по свойству document.location (если разные файлы создают разные страницы)
2 по анализу тела документа (идентификаторы,классы,тесты)